# No such column on sqlite android query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am running a query but it returns no such column. I copy and pasted the column into sqlite viewer and it is running with no errors.

```
String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT m.* FROM '21_cars_models' as m INNER JOIN ( '41_cars_models_galleries' as mg 
INNER JOIN ( '24_galleries' as g 
INNER JOIN ( '26_galleries_pictures' as gp INNER JOIN '25_pictures' as p ON gp.picture_id=p._id ) 
ON g._id=gp.gallery_id ) ON mg.gallery_id=g._id ) 
ON m._id=mg.model_id WHERE m.brand_id LIKE '" + markaID + "'";
```

```
02-12 13:58:09.881: E/MYAPP(10962): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: gp.gallery_id (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT m.*  FROM '21_cars_models' as m INNER JOIN ( '41_cars_models_galleries' as mg INNER JOIN ( '24_galleries' as g INNER JOIN ( '26_galleries_pictures' as gp INNER JOIN '25_pictures' as p ON gp.picture_id=p._id ) ON g._id=gp.gallery_id ) ON mg.gallery_id=g._id ) ON m._id=mg.model_id WHERE m.brand_id LIKE '339'
```

EDIT:
If i remove all INNER JOIN and run it is everything fine. I can't understand why with INNER JOIN things is blowing. Again to remind that if i run this directly to database is everyting fine....

Comment: Post all ur code & the screenshot of ur sqlite database

Comment: Please, send a evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot make inner join with parenthesis.... i turned my query like

From a INNER JOIN b ON a.id=b.id INNER JOIN c ON c.id=b.id INNER JOIN d ON d.id=c.id

And it worked perfectly...

Thanks everyone for your time....

Comment: any reference that inner join can't have paranthesis?